# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-active-directory

My JSON is as follows

```
{
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$metadata#users",
   "value":[
      {
         "businessPhones":[

         ],
         "displayName":"dee",
         "givenName":null,
         "jobTitle":null,
         "mail":"79@gmail.com",
         "mobilePhone":null,
         "officeLocation":null,
         "preferredLanguage":null,
         "surname":null,
         "userPrincipalName":"79_gmail.com#EXT#@web.onmicrosoft.com",
         "id":"08fab3-6f-4dc9-9ffb-6568d172"
      },
      {
         "businessPhones":[
            "973"
         ],
         "displayName":"Technologies LLP",
         "givenName":"SHA",
         "jobTitle":null,
         "mail":null,
         "mobilePhone":"8762",
         "officeLocation":null,
         "preferredLanguage":"en-U",
         "surname":"SHAI",
         "userPrincipalName":"admin@web.onmicrosoft.com",
         "id":"2adf-94cd-45-83ef-d0dbf1e36"
      },
      {
         "businessPhones":[

         ],
         "displayName":"admin of smartogle",
         "givenName":null,
         "jobTitle":null,
         "mail":null,
         "mobilePhone":null,
         "officeLocation":null,
         "preferredLanguage":"en-US",
         "surname":null,
         "userPrincipalName":"admin@smartogle.com",
         "id":"1754-d6-40-9ae2-d816063e"
      },
      {
         "businessPhones":[

         ],
         "displayName":"av",
         "givenName":null,
         "jobTitle":null,
         "mail":null,
         "mobilePhone":null,
         "officeLocation":null,
         "preferredLanguage":"en-US",
         "surname":null,
         "userPrincipalName":"av@smartogle.com",
         "id":"6837-08-449-a6ab-78b"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using the following code to convert the json to the object list

```
MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(members);
```

MyObject Class is as follows

```cs
public class MyError
{
    public List<values> value;
}
public class values
{
    public string id;
    public string userPrincipalName;
    public string surname;
    public string preferredLanguage;
    public string officeLocation;
    public string mobilePhone;
    public string mail;
    public string jobTitle;
    public string givenName;
    public string displayName;
    public string businessPhones;

}
```

While converting I am getting the following error

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'value[0].businessPhones', line 1, position 97.

When I delete the public string businessPhones; from the class the rest of the data are parsed to the object list. But actually I need the businessPhones also

Comment: What is `List` in `public List value;`? Also `businessPhones` is an array in your JSON. Simple solution to JSON deserialization problems like this: compare your model to your JSON.

Comment: `businessPhones` is `multi value`  fields and you have define as string.

Comment: ```businessPhones``` seems to be an array of string, so you should declare it as such

Comment: thank you converting businessPhones to  array list solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as several folks pointed about you should declare `businessPhones` as array:

```
public string[] businessPhones;
```